# How to make select query alias as query --mysql or postgresql or sqlite

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, syntax, alias

I want to make query with alias but need changeable alias as name .
for example this is simple query :

```
"SELECT col1 AS 'first name' , col2 AS 'second name' FROM my_table ";
```

now I need change result like below:

```
"SELECT 
col1 AS ("SELECT difin FROM languge WHERE word = 'col1' "),
col2 AS ("SELECT difin FROM languge WHERE word = 'col2' ")
FROM my_table "
```

I tried make function but after 'AS' can't accept any syntax.

Comment: Could you share the function you tried to make?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  As is, it's difficult to understand what you are attempting to do.

Comment: What you are looking for is problably Dynamic SQL. In PostgreSQL for instance you could have it not directly in SQL (it is not implemented, like in other open source systems), but in the PL/pgSQL language (see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-statements.html), section “40.5.4. Executing Dynamic Commands” later in that page.

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION lang_ch(word TEXT CHARSET utf8)
  RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT ch FROM lang where var=word LIMIT 1);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: Actually i want use column name for separate languages .

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using multiple `joins`:

```
select l.difin col1,
       l2.difin col2
from my_table t 
      join language l on t.col1 = l.word
      join language l2 on t.col2 = l2.word
```

Depending on your data, you may need to use an `outer join` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here I made the samples below.

[image: Sample1]
[image: Sample2]